# Prove that a finite language is regular

Tags: automata, regular-languages

I want to prove that $L(G) = \{01; 11110; 10101; 000\}$ is regular.

Is it correct if I write there exists a regular expression, which is: $(01|11110|10101|000)$?

How can I also prove it using a DFA?

Comment: `Prove that a finite language is regular` Really.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression is correct.

You can use a trie-like structure, i.e.

[image: DFA for finite language]